# $(window).one('scroll' is triggered on refresh from middle of the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome, onscroll

On Chrome, when I refresh while not at the very top of the page, the `$(window).one('scroll'` function is triggered immediately upon page load. I have a landing page that disappears when the user scrolls. But the landing page is disappearing immediately if I refresh the page while not at the top.

I tried adding
`document.body.scrollTop = 0;`
`document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;`
above the `$(window).one('scroll'` but that didn't work.

How can I reset the page to the top BEFORE Chrome reads the `$(window).one('scroll'` function?
Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

That's actually correct behavior, the browser will scroll the page, and in normal circumstances we want to know about it, so it's normal the event is fired.
Unfortunately, when this event will fire isn't very well specified, so we have to resort on some magic numbers like

```
onload = (evt) => setTimeout(() => {
    addEventListener("scroll", callback, { once: true });
  }, 1000); // hopefully 1s after full page load the browser will have computed the new scrolling position
```

but that may very well fail, moreover if there is a lot of content being dynamically added in the page at load time.

If this is a deal breaker for you, maybe you'd be interested in preventing the page from restoring the scroll position at load, for this you can use [`history.scrollRestoration = "manual"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/scrollRestoration).

Another option would be to only listen to scroll events that do happen inside your landing page, instead of listening to every ones that happen in the page, and to reset this wrapper's scroll position after you hide the landing page, so that at the next reload the browser doesn't need to restore it.